# Bitbucket doesn't create visual branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm new to git and working with bitbucket.
Did I do something wrong that bitbucket doesn't show a visual branch? It looks like i'm still working in master.
I have other commits before in the master branch.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not do anything wrong. Bitbucket shows your commit history just like it is: a linear list of commits (some of which have branches pointing to them). In git, a branch is merely a pointer to a commit.

As soon as you make divergent commits on the two branches, you will see two visual branches on the graph.

Comment: And how do I set up the Bruches to commit?